# if, in $\ell^2$ space, the sums doesn't start from $1$....

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $\{x_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $\ell^2$ such that $x_m \to x$

Let $x_{m,n}$ be the nth number in the $x_m$ sequence and $x_n$ be the nth number in the $x$ sequence.

Fixed an integer $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$ is it true that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}
\sqrt{
\sum_{n=\lambda}^\infty
|x_{m,n}|^2
}
=
\sqrt{
\sum_{n=\lambda}^\infty
|x_n|^2
}
$$

thanks.

Comment: It is not important that the sum does not start from one. Do you know how to solve it when $\lambda=1$?

Comment: yes, i use the continuos norm, but i'm not sure the $\lambda>1$

Comment: Look at $\left\|x_n\right\|^2-(x_n,e_1)-(x_n,e_2)-...-(x_n,e_{\lambda -1})$, where $e_i=(0,0,...,1,0,...)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is true. This is a consequence of the continuity of the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ norm function.

In general for a norm, you have the inequality:
$$\vert \Vert x \Vert - \Vert y \Vert \vert \le \Vert x - y \Vert $$

Hence if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$, you also have as a consequence of inequality above
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \Vert x_n \Vert= \Vert x \Vert$

On top of that, you can prove that the left $\lambda$-shift linear application
$$ x=(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_\lambda, \dots ) \mapsto S_\lambda(x)=(x_\lambda, x_{\lambda+1}, \dots)$$ is continuous in $\ell_2$ as $\Vert S_\lambda(x) \Vert_2 \le \Vert x \Vert_2$.

Therefore
$$\vert \Vert S_\lambda(x_n) \Vert_2-\Vert S_\lambda(x) \Vert_2 \vert \le \Vert S_\lambda(x_n-x) \Vert_2 \le \Vert x_n - x \Vert_2$$

gives the conclusion $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \Vert S_\lambda(x_n) \Vert_2 = \Vert S_\lambda(x) \Vert_2$$ which is exactly your equality.

**This proof is not using the inner product.**

Comment: thanks @mathcounterexamples.net for your nice proof

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ denote the standard orthonormal basis of $\ell_2$.
For $\lambda\in\mathbb{N}$, let $P_{\lambda}$ denote the projection onto the linear span of $\{e_n\}_{n\geq\lambda}$. Then, 
$$|\!|P_{\lambda}x_m|\!|^2=\sum_{n\geq\lambda}|x_{m,n}|^2$$
and
$$|\!|P_{\lambda}x|\!|^2=\sum_{n\geq\lambda}|x_n|^2$$
and so what you are asking is whether $|\!|P_{\lambda}x_m|\!|$ tends to $|\!|P_{\lambda}x|\!|$ as $m\to\infty$. Now, since the projection $P_{\lambda}$ is a bounded linear operator (it's norm is clearly $1$), it is continuous, and since $x_m\to x$, it follows that $P_{\lambda}x_m\to P_{\lambda}x$ as $m\to\infty$, and in particular, the norms also converge to the corresponding norm.

Comment: thanks @uniquesolution for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You seem to know how to prove this for $\lambda=1$ and only the $\lambda$ itself raises your confusion. So just define the sequences

$$y_{m,n}:=x_{m,n+\lambda-1}$$

which look exactly like the $x$-sequences, but shifted to the left by an amount of $\lambda-1$. Now your claim is identical to

$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}
\sqrt{
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
|y_{m,n}|^2
}
=
\sqrt{
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
|y_n|^2
}
$$

which you said you can prove.

**Note**: Summation indices (and indices in general) are just arbitrarily defined to start at one (or zero sometimes) and there is noting special about it. If they start at $\lambda$, this does not need any special care as long as we are in some general setting.

---

**Note**: Rewriting the question like this is only valid when we know

$$\lim x_n = x\quad\implies\quad\lim y_n= y$$

where $y$ is $x$ shifted to the left by $\lambda-1$.

Comment: ok @M. Winter  you clarify my question... now i understand it

Comment: @M. Winter If I may, I think that you're missing one point here. Which is WHY if $\lim x_n =x$ you have $\lim y_n = y$. This is not (totally) evident. The initial hypothesis is NOT $\lim y_n = y$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i think you are right

Comment: @M.Winter I understand. However, if you look carefully at the initial question of Matey, the key point is precisely that one.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Probably you are right and I am hiding the non-trivial part.